# If $(A-\lambda I)^r q(A) =0$ then $q(V) \subset \text{ker}(A-\lambda I)^r$

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

I was reading [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/938338/695196) to a question about the multiplicity of the roots in the minimal polynomial. The hypothesis of the original question is as follows:

> Let $ V\neq \{0 \}$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $F$ and let $A \in \text{End}(V)$

At the beginning of the answer, I was reading the author establishes the following:

> We have $(A-\lambda I)^r q(A) =0$, which is to say that $q(V) \subset \text{ker}(A-\lambda I)^r$

I understand that the first equation is $0$ because by definition the minimal polynomial annihilates the transformation to which it's related to, but I don't see how this implies the second part. It is my understanding that $ \text{ker}(A-\lambda I)^r$ is the set of all generalized eigenvectors associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda$, so is this saying that *any* vector in $V$ applied to the polynomial $q$ is a generalized eigenvector?

Can someone tell me why this implication holds or tell me what I'm missing? Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:** The original author of the question edited his answer to have $q(A)V$ instead of $q(A)$, which is what some people already said they suspected in the comments of this question.

Comment: What does $q(V)$ even mean?

Comment: In the original question they define it to be the vector space on which the endomorphism acts. I'll edit my post to include this.

Comment: Yes $V$ is the vector space, but that still does not explain what $q(V)$ means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a linear operator $A : V \to V$ and a polynomial $q(t)$ such that $(A - \lambda I)^r q(A) = 0,$ it follows that $(A - \lambda I)^r q(A)(v) = 0(v) = 0$ for all $v$ in $V,$ hence we have $\operatorname{range}(q(A)) \subseteq \ker(A - \lambda I)^r.$ Considering that $\operatorname{range}(q(A)) = q(A)(V)$ by definition, we conclude that $q(A)(V) \subseteq \ker(A - \lambda I)^r.$

Answer (score -1):

The kernel of an operator $T\in \Bbb L(V$) is defined by $\{v\in V \mid T(v)=0\}$. Hence $(A-\lambda I)^r q(A) =0$ is exactly the same as saying every  $q(A)(v) \subset \text{ker}(A-\lambda I)^r\; \forall v\in V$

(I believe the V was supposed to be A. I've learned this part in Linear Algebra but we never used q(V) with V a vector space.)

Comment: But isn't $q(A)$ an operator itself? Since $A$ is an endomorphism then $q(A)$ would result in another operator, so it wouldn't be a set, right?

Comment: I never said q(A) is a set. The role of q(A) here in the context of the definition of kernel is the same as the element v, which q(A) certainly can be seen as one.

Comment: I think I got confused with the notation. If I understood correctly, does the symbol "$\subset$" not mean subset in your answer?

Comment: I fear there is a fundamental misunderstanding in this answer. Observe that $q(A)$ is an operator; however, $\ker(A - \lambda I)^r = \{v \in V \,|\, (A - \lambda I)^r(v) = 0\},$ where $0$ in this case is the zero vector of $V.$ Hence, it does not make sense to say that $q(A)$ is contained in the kernel of the operator $(A - \lambda I)^r.$

Comment: @Carlo You're right; the q(A) I wrote should actually be q(A)(v), where v is any vector in V